# DataStax OpsCenter v5.2.4 Create Cluster Error

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, opscenter

Using DataStax OpsCenter v5.2.4 (currently the latest) installed using AMI `ami-8f3e2bbf` provided by DataStax and following [DataStax's instructions on how to create a cluster on EC2](http://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.8/datastax_enterprise/install/installAMIOpsc.html), all DSE nodes fail during creation with this error:

```
Install Errored: Could not find a matching version for package dse-libpig
```

Is there a work around for this?

Note that during the process I selected Package: DataStax Enterprise 4.8.1, which is the latest available in the list at this time.

Comment: Can you double-check that in the OpsCenter UI, your DataStax and Amazon AWS credentials don't have any leading or trailing spaces? I think there can be problems with extra spaces there that lead to this dse-libpig error.

Comment: Yes, I have double checked all credentials - there is no leading or trailing spaces and all credentials are valid. I've also tried this >10 times, spanning two AWS regions and also rebuilt OpsCenter node 4 times and also tried manually adding DSE 4.8.5 based on the instructions of the post from 3 years ago with this same error. Nothing has worked.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and taking a clue from BrianC's comment resolved by removing a trailing '@' in my datastax account password

Comment: This warrants a clarification - just change your password to not contain the at (`@`) character (I don't know if it's a problem for trailing `@`, but that sure breaks the installation)